# How would I not apply the replace method in a list to a specific item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just wondering how I would not have the replace method applied to a specific item in a list (but to the rest). In this example, how I would not apply it to the 3rd item (the 'c' string)?

```
ls_c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
ls_c_a = (','.join(ls_c))
ls_c_a_1 = ls_c_a.replace(',', '\n')
print('test' + ls_c_a_1)
```

So the output would look like:

```
testa
bc
d
e
f
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case its better to manually build new string in for loop

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the 3rd item will always be "c" string, you could try this:

```
ls_c_a_1 = ''.join([item if "b" in item else item + "\n" for item in ls_c_a.split(",")])
```

If this value can be changed, use this:

```
ls_c_a_1 = [item + "\n" for item in ls_c_a.split(",")]
ls_c_a_2 = ''.join([a[i].replace("\n", "") if i == 1 else a[i] for i in range(len(a))])
```

Comment: Using your output as metric, because if you want to keep the "," between "b" and "c", just change the replace to replace("\n", ",")

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find all instances of commas where a **c** doesn't succeed the comma, using a negative lookahead (`?!`):

`,(?![c])`

Then, you can use the `Pattern.sub()` method to substitute all discovered commas with a newline.

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = ",".join(ls_c)
>>> regex = re.compile(r",(?![c])")
>>> print(regex.sub("\n", string))
a
b,c
d
e
f
```